# x11 zbar compilation issue for ARM platform

Tags: cross-platform, x11, zbar, v4l2

I require a help regarding the building process of Zbar. 
I am trying to cross compile zbar-0.10 source for i.Mx6DualLite platform and When I give the below configure, X11 is throwing error "unable to find XvQueryExtension in -lXv!". Please help to fix this issue. I want to run the zbar scanner in my i.Mx6DL platform using v4l2 application. X11 is required since the video need to be showen on the LCD screen.

Below is my configure command.

```
./configure --without-xshm --with-xv --without-python --without-gtk --without-qt --without-imagemagick --host=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi CFLAGS=-I/home/user/Haji/ZBAR/Yocto/imx6dlsabresd/usr/include/ LDFLAGS=-L/home/user/Haji/ZBAR/Yocto/imx6dlsabresd/usr/lib/
configure: WARNING: If you wanted to set the --build type, don't use --host.
If a cross compiler is detected then cross compile mode will be used.
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-strip... arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-strip
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-poky-linux-gnueabi
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc... arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc... gcc3
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc... /opt/poky/1.6.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.8.2/ld
checking if the linker (/opt/poky/1.6.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.8.2/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /opt/poky/1.6.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi//arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-nm -B
checking the name lister (/opt/poky/1.6.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi//arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking for /opt/poky/1.6.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.8.2/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump... arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-ar... arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-ar
checking for arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-strip... (cached) arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-strip
checking for arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-ranlib... arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-ranlib
checking command to parse /opt/poky/1.6.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi//arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-nm -B output from arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc object... ok
checking how to run the C preprocessor... arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc linker (/opt/poky/1.6.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.8.2/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for shl_load... no
checking for shl_load in -ldld... no
checking for dlopen... no
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking whether a program can dlopen itself... cross
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-windres... no
checking for windres... no
checking host system type... (cached) arm-poky-linux-gnueabi
checking for arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc... (cached) arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking dependency style of arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking whether arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking for arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++... arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++... gcc3
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking dependency style of arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++... (cached) gcc3
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ -E
checking for ld used by arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++... /opt/poky/1.6.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.8.2/ld
checking if the linker (/opt/poky/1.6.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.8.2/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ linker (/opt/poky/1.6.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.8.2/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ linker (/opt/poky/1.6.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.8.2/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-pkg-config... no
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
configure: WARNING: using cross tools not prefixed with host triplet
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for xmlto... xmlto
checking whether to build EAN symbologies... yes
checking whether to build Code 128 symbology... yes
checking whether to build Code 39 symbology... yes
checking whether to build PDF417 symbology... no
checking whether to build Interleaved 2 of 5 symbology... yes
checking whether to build QR Code... yes
checking for library containing clock_gettime... none required
checking for ld used by GCC... /opt/poky/1.6.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.8.2/ld
checking if the linker (/opt/poky/1.6.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.8.2/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for shared library run path origin... done
checking for iconv... yes
checking for working iconv... guessing yes
checking for iconv declaration...
extern size_t iconv (iconv_t cd, char * inbuf, size_t inbytesleft, char * outbuf, size_t outbytesleft);
checking poll.h usability... yes
checking poll.h presence... yes
checking for poll.h... yes
checking pthread.h usability... yes
checking pthread.h presence... yes
checking for pthread.h... yes
checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... yes
checking linux/videodev2.h usability... yes
checking linux/videodev2.h presence... yes
checking for linux/videodev2.h... yes
checking for linux/videodev2.h... (cached) yes
checking for X... no
checking for X11/extensions/Xvlib.h... yes
checking for XvQueryExtension in -lXv... no
configure: error: in /home/user/Haji/ZBAR/zbar-0.10': configure: error: unable to find XvQueryExtension in -lXv! specify XV_LIBS or configure --without-xv to disable the extension Seeconfig.log' for more details
```

.

Please help. I am completely struck up with this.

Thanks in advance
Regards
Sarjoon

Comment: Well the first question to ask is, do you *have* libXv.so on your target machine?

Comment: yes, I have, I checked the folder -L/home/user/Haji/ZBAR/Yocto/imx6dlsabresd/usr/lib/ and Xv.so is there and even all X11 libraries are there. But this issue points out to some other lib like "Xv Extension". Do I have to link through any commands other than LDFLAGS ?

Comment: OK now you need to look at the config.log and see the exact error. Maybe configure didn't honor LDFLAGS. Or maybe libXv.so is compiuled for a different architecture. Or it could be a different error altogether (not an unresolved symbol). Also look what exact error caused the "checking for X... no" message.

Comment: issue is resolved. Thanks for the response. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue we can able to resolve now. We looked into the config.log and found some X11 libs are missing and all X11 related libs and headers files need to be linked  with these X11 commands -> XV_LIBS and X_CFLAGS flags. With this it compile successfully and X11 worked well

This is the final command with X11 configured.

./configure --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --without-python --without-imagemagick --without-gtk --without-xshm --without-qt --disable-pthread CFLAGS=-I/home/user/YOCTO/exe/usr/include LDFLAGS=-L/home/user/YOCTO/exe/usr/lib/ XV_LIBS=-L/home/user/YOCTO/exe/usr/lib/ LIBS=-lXext -lX11 -lXau -lXdmcp -lxcb -lXv -luuid X_CFLAGS=-I/home/user/YOCTO/exe/usr/include/